# React Hot Reload (auto refresh) is only working in index.html, but in .js files

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React.js.
The problem I am having is that hot reloading 'auto refresh' is not working when I do 'CRTL + s'. It works when I do 'CRTL + s' in index.html file, but doesnt work in any .js file.
(after saving the changes in .js file and go to index.html file, it works. Changes in .js file appear in the app, but nothing happens while making changes in .js file and saving).

I tried thousands of things and searched online alot, but nothing is working for me.
Thanks

Comment: How are you implementing hot reload? Are your using `create-react-app`?

Comment: Problem Solved. I used 'npm install -g create-react-app' first and then 'create-react-app my-app' and It did the job. now everything is working like charm. Still dont know what it did and the main reason, but for now, problem solved and life is easy :D

Comment: `create-react-app` is a tool to create react development environments easily. The default configuration includes hot reload